# Solutions of polynomials with p-adic coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory

I'm studying p-adic numbers in "A course in Arithmetic" by Serre. I need some help to understand a proposition about solutions of polynomials with p-adic coefficients. I've seen that there is already a question about this proposition here:

[II. p-adic equations [2.1. Solutions] (J.-P. Serre)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757946/ii-p-adic-equations-2-1-solutions-j-p-serre)

I'm interested in the first proposition after the lemma:

Proposition: Let $f^{(i)} \in \mathbb{Z}_p[X1,…,Xm]$ be polynomials with p-adic integer coefficients. The following are equivalent:

i) The $f^{(i)}$ have a common zero in $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^m$.

ii) For all $n>1$ the polynomials $f^{(i)}_n$ have a common zero in $(A_n)^m$.

Here $A_n=\mathbb{Z}/{p^n\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p=\lim A_n$.

$f_n$ is the polynomial $f$ reduced mod $p^n$.

In the proof Serre says that, if $D$ is the set of the common zeros in $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^m$ and $D_n$ of common zeros in $(A_n)^m$, then $D=\lim D_n$. Then he applies a lemma to say that $D$ is non empty if and only if the $D_n$ are non empty. I have understand the lemma but i don't understand why $D=\lim D_n$ and how to prove it. I'm not sure about reducing mod $p^n$ a polynomial. Is it equivalent to take only the $n$ components of coefficients?

Thanks to anyone who will help me.

Comment: “Reducing mod $p^n$” just means treating each coefficient as being in $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$ instead. There is a canonical ring morphism $\Bbb Z_p\to\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$, so just apply it to the coefficients.

Comment: thanks! so in this way i can prove that if $D$ is non empty, the $D_n$ are non empty, right? can you have any suggestions about proving that $D=\lim D_n$?

Comment: Does it suffice to show that, given a solution $x_n$ in $(A_n)^m$, i can construct a solution $x_{n+1}$ in $(A_{n+1})^m$ such that $x_n \equiv x_{n+1}$ mod $p^n$? but how can I do this? Do i have to use the solution in $(A_{n+1})^m$ that exists by hypothesis?

Comment: To your first question, I suppose that that’s the definition of $D$. For the second question, it does suffice. The process of going from $A_n$ to $A_{n+1}$ is exactly Hensel’s Lemma, which I think you’ll need to justify in each particular case. Hensel itself, of course, does not directly apply. But there’s no doubt about what Serre says.